DynamoDb: How to set a nested value on a record that may not exist
Considering that the dynamodb item/record may not exist, and this needs to be an upsert operation only on the intended path, I'm trying to do this with an UpdateCommand.
Here's my UpdateExpression:
SET #attachments = if_not_exists(#attachments, :emptyRecord), 
    #attachments.#attachmentId = :attachmentRecord

I get this error:

ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Two document paths overlap with each other; must remove or rewrite one of these paths; path one: [attachments], path two: [attachments, attachmentId]

I'm only interested in having this work in a single mutation, not including transactions.

The simple answer is that it's not possible. The best way to overcome it is to always add an empty set to the creation of the item.
myitem = {
   pk: 'foo'
   sk: 'bar'
   attachments: {}
}


This is not gonna work for my case, as creating these records unless necessary, will mean wasting significant amount of resources. I appreciate the authoritative answer, regardless.
